# Ajax asmx page no error

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, web-services, asp.net-ajax

I am trying to make a ajax web service call with the following:

JQuery:

```
window.setInterval(function () {

            var reponse = '';
            $.ajax({
                 type: "post",
                 url: "http://ws/page.asmx/Test",
                 contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                 data: "{}",
                 dataType: "json",                   
                 success: function (data) {

                 reponse = data.d;
                $("#timer").text(reponse);
                alert("updated");
             },

             error: function (xhr, textStatus, err) {
                 console.log("readyState: " + xhr.readyState);
                 console.log("responseText: " + xhr.responseText);
                 console.log("status: " + xhr.status);
                 console.log("text status: " + textStatus);
                 console.log("error: " + err);
                 console.log("******************************");

             }
         });
    }, 3000);//time in milliseconds
```

C# Web Method

```
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]

  [WebMethod]
  [ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true, ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
  public string Test() {
       return "Hello World";
  }
```

And my ajax returns the following:

```
"******************************" 
"readyState: 0" 
"responseText: " 
"status: 0" 
"text status: "
"error: " 
"******************************"
```

How can I determine what the issue is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the url you are calling does not allow cross region calls.
There can be a problem with CORS.
You can get information about CORS easily.